# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on filter

Tags: php

I have a column where I'm pulling in objects from `Recipe` and getting the names back, but some posts don't have 'required' authors yet and I'm getting a debug error back - Is it possible to set a 'No authors available' echo if there are no array/objects being returned?

Here is the code:

```
add_action('manage_post_posts_custom_column', function($column, $post_id) {
    switch ($column) {
        case 'authors':

            $recipe = Recipe::init($post_id);

            if (is_array($recipe) || is_object($recipe))
            {
                foreach ($recipe->get_authors() as $profile) {
                    $arr[] = '<a href="' . $profile->get_url() . '">' . $profile->get_name() . '</a>';
                }
                echo implode($arr, ', ');
                break;
            } else {
                echo 'No authors';
            }
    }
}, 10, 3);
```

Here in the screenshot below, you can see my first post has `authors`, but the second post doesn't have them set yet.

[image]

`var_dump(is_object($recipe))` returns true for the first post.

Could someone tell me what I might be doing wrong?

```
public function set_authors($authors)
{
    $profiles = [];

    foreach ($authors as $author) {
        $profiles[] = Profile::init($author);
    }

    $this->authors = $profiles;
}

public function get_authors()
{
    return $this->authors;
}
```

Comment: Why not check for authors before looping? Have you tried dumping that `$recipe` object, or tried anything else in terms of debugging?

Comment: private 'authors' on $recipe is empty on the other posts.

Comment: Well, then you shouldn't loop over that empty property

Comment: if `$recipe` is an array, `->` is not right.

Comment: I would alter `get_authors()` to return an empty array (as opposed to, I'm guessing, null) when there are no authors set.

Comment: `if (!empty($recipe->get_authors()))
            {
                foreach ($recipe->get_authors() as $profile) {
                    $arr[] = '<a href="' . $profile->get_url() . '">' . $profile->get_name() . '</a>';
                }
                echo implode($arr, ', ');
                break;
            } else {
                echo 'No authors available.';
            }`

So I've got the text to pop up using the following method, but I'm still getting a debug error.

Comment: Hey man! show us the get_authors() function!

Comment: @EbrahimMohammed, hey man! I've updated the getter and setter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go! You also had a problem in implode, you were passing the array then the glue, but it had to be the other way around.

```
add_action('manage_post_posts_custom_column', function ($column, $post_id) {
    switch ($column) {
        case 'authors':

            $recipe = Recipe::init($post_id);

            if (is_array($recipe) || is_object($recipe)) {
                $authors = $recipe->get_authors();

                if (isset($authors) && !empty($authors)) {
                    $arr = array();
                    foreach ($authors as $profile) {
                        $arr[] = '<a href="' . $profile->get_url() . '">' . $profile->get_name() . '</a>';
                    }
                    echo implode(', ', $arr);
                    break;
                }
                echo "No Authors";
                break;
            } else {
                echo 'No authors';
            }
    }
}, 10, 3);
```

Update, change set_authors to:

```
public function set_authors($authors)
{
    $profiles = [];
    if(!empty($authors)){
        foreach ($authors as $author) {
            $profiles[] = Profile::init($author);
        }
    }
    $this->authors = $profiles;
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I've tried the above code and I'm still getting `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` error - I updated the post with the getter and setter.

Comment: Can I see the recipe.php line 148?

Comment: Its showing `foreach ($authors as $author) {` inside the set_authors method. @Ebrahim

Answer (score 0):

You must Check on
$recipe->get_authors()

And not on $recipe

I can understand that $recipe is an object but $recipe->get_authors() is the array that you use on foreach.

If so you have to check if $recipe->get_authors() is an array before your foreach

Comment: thanks man! I've updated the post with the getter and setters